# Can a UK passport valid for two months travel to Germany post-brexit?

Tags: passports, germany, uk-citizens, brexit

If I had a UK passport which was due to expire on February 1st, 2020 - less than 6 months from now, would I be allowed to make a weekend visit to Germany?

Comment: The point made in like questions was 'when was the passport made' as the new rules do not allow more than 10 years of use out of your passport. For the rest, we do now yet know when or even whether Brexit happens.

Comment: You can check whether your current passport is valid for future / post-Brexit travel [here](https://www.passport.service.gov.uk/check-a-passport).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As I understand it.

Under the brexit deals that were negotiated by the government but not passed  by Parliament there is supposed to be a transition period lasting at least until the end of 2020. Freedom of movement would continue during this transition period. So you would be ok to travel in February on your existing passport.

On the other hand, in the event of a no-deal brexit it is most likely that the Schengen area would treat UK visitors like other foreigners which means you would need a passport that was issued within the last 10 years and with at least 3 months validity beyond the end of your trip, so your passport would not be acceptable.

Comment: Why do you think Schengen area would not require a visa? Is there a valid visa waiver agreement in case of no deal brexit?

Comment: I don't have a link handy but IIRC the EU have announced as part of their no-deal brexit preperations that they will not initially require Visas in the event of a no-deal brexit, but that maintenance of this status long-term will depend on the UK reciprocating. It's also likely that the schengen area will introduce an advance authorisation system that they insist is not a visa (similar to the US esta and the canadian ETA) but afaict that is not scheduled to come into force until 2021.

Comment: [Supporting documentation from the European Commission concerning travel after a no-deal](https://ec.europa.eu/info/sites/info/files/factsheet_1_travel_en_final.pdf). I don't believe that potential reciprocal arrangements on visa-free travel change the basic requirement that 3 months be left on the passport.

Comment: Nit: The latest Brexit deal was *not* rejected by Parliament - indeed it actually passed the second reading.  What was rejected was an attempt to railroad it through in a very short time (in time to meet the October 31st deadline) - and the government declined to bring it back with a longer timescale.

Comment: @lalala visa exemptions are not always effected by agreement.  For example, the EU disagrees with the fact that the US does not grant visa waivers to all EU citizens, yet US citizens continue to enjoy visa-free access to all EU countries.  Another example: there are literally dozens of countries whose citizens require visas to enter the EU but not vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

This is a badly formed question because your passport expiry is the same as the Brexit crash-out date! So you are only asking about 2 use cases: a) Britain still in EU, or b) passport is expired.  Black-boxing [Traveler's link](https://www.passport.service.gov.uk/check-a-passport): **After a crash-out Brexit, you cannot travel on an expired passport** end of inquiry.

Anti-DV Disclaimer: I'm referring to a UK citizen traveling to Germany, since that is OP. I answer questions in context.

FYI, after a crash-out Brexit, your passport becomes useless for German travel 9.5 years after its issuance, *or* within 6 (not 3) months of its expiry, whichever happens sooner.

If you're asking "well, what happens on a yes-deal Brexit?", ask on politics.se because that depends on the deal. Nobody knows. The link assumes the only thing we do know, which is crash-out.

Comment: Is there a source for "9.5 years after its issuance or within 6 months of expiry"? Article 50 of the EU treaty states _"blah blah agreement, otherwise treaty end"_. So, in my understanding, if there is a crash out without agreement, it's "end". The treaty no longer applies to the leaving party. Which means as much as who cares when the passport was issued, or how long it's valid, you'll need a valid visa. Without that, the passport is entirely useless, even if it was valid for 250 years.

Comment: @Damon The country you wish to enter desides if they will accept your passport. The 10 year max is based on the ICAO Passport norms which most countries now require. 
**Schengen Border Code Article 3 (1)(a), Entry conditions third country nationals**

Comment: @MarkJohnson: Ah, found it, thanks. It's Article 6(1)(a) though, not 3. Note paragraph (b) too, however: _"in possession of a valid visa if required"_ (where "if required" means as much as "except excepted", which surely isn't the case as presently UK is still a member). Also (c) "justify purpose... sufficient means of subsistence, blah blah". So, I think that all alone by itseslf, the passport would be useless. It is just _one_ precondition among many.

Comment: @Damon Sorry, Article 6 will only apply after the UK leaves the EU. The UK will be listed in Annex II (countries that don't need a Visa). All of this only if no other special agreement is made. At present only proof of EU-Citizenship is required, where it seems that an expired passport is sufficient.

Comment: @Damon Not sure what you meen that a passport alone is useless. Since a UK Citizen only has a passport, it will be needed. Then Article 6 (1)(a,c,d,e) will then apply.

Comment: @MarkJohnson: Well yes, the Q is "post-Brexit" so my baseline assumption was "UK not in EU". We're probably misunderstanding each other. When I say "useless", I mean that insofar as you certainly need a passport, but you **also** need a visa, and need to comply with the other conditions. As in: it's nowhere near certain that it's good for crossing the border (if you get denied visa, for example).

Comment: @Damon I believe official statements have been made, that British citizens will be listed in Annex II, thus will **not** need a visa, but must comply with the 90/180 days rules.

Comment: @Damon This was conditional on the UK not imposing Visas for EU-Citizens, which no one has hinted at from the UK  side. (This assumes only short stay visits)

Comment: @Damon  Source = the link.  Try it with several passport issue dates; the issue becomes readily apparent.  Remember to select "Germany" for the country!  My answer is not a blanket statement; it is an answer.  Answers are only meaningful in the context of a question, and I state that more explicitly than usual.  I loathe having to write disclaimers that my answer only applies to OP, ought to be implied.

Comment: @MarkJohnson You would certainly expect some sort of visa waiver program between UK and EU.  Of course that does nothing to cure the *passport*...

Comment: "your passport expiry is the same as the Brexit crash-out date!" as far as I can tell passport expiry dates are the last day the day is valid, so there is potentially one day on which the OPs passport is valid, but not acceptable to the Schengen area after a no-deal brexit.

Comment: @MarkJohnson the free movement directive allows countries to require that EU citizens possess a valid travel document, and as far as I know Germany does that, so an expired passport from an EU country is not sufficient to travel to Germany.

Comment: Harper: 9.5 years is incorrect.  The Schengen requirement is that the passport be valid for three months after anticipated departure, so someone whose passport expires in 3.5 months can enter the Schengen area for two weeks.

Comment: @PeterGreen the Brexit crash-out *time* is 11 PM UK time, so it's more like one hour.

Comment: Yeah seriously @PeterGreen you're really taking pedantry to "eleven"... has no one ever taught you pedantry is not constructive?

Comment: @phoog Yet the link disagrees. Try plugging in a few creation dates at relevant times.  I  was aware of the 3 month / 6 month issue (in fact, had to chase a bug around that; I was entering 3/1 for March 1, whoops).  So I indeed black-boxed it for that very question, both in terms of 9.5 vs 9.75 year from issue, and 3 vs 6 month expiry. *Mind you I tested Germany not Schengen; I can't possibly speak to situations outside the question's scope.*

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica that the linked tool gives inaccurate results is inevitable because the tool is inadequate.  It does not ask for the date of departure from the Schengen area.